# Custom Checkout Validation - Two fields must have the same value

Tags: magento2, validation, form-validation

I've created a module which adds an additional field to the checkout, called 'email-confirm'.
I want to check that the value in this field is equal to the first email entry, but I'm unsure how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The registration form is worth having a look over it uses the following:

```
data-validate="{required:true, equalTo:'#password'}"
```

So based on that, if you have a template you should add a specific validator for equalTo and the target which you wish to compare it to.

If your using it through xml to build your form similar to the checkout I expect that you can add it as an item eg:

```
<item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="equalTo" xsi:type="string">#target</item>
</item>
```

The above I've not verified however but believe that way should work.

Comment: Thanks for you response, I've just tried this method and while it seems to be valid xml it doesn't seem to apply the validation. I've replaced the #target with #customer-email and but when I submit the form without filling this in - it succeeds rather than prevents you from submitting (as it should).

Comment: This didn't work due to another issue in my xml, works now - thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work using a overwrite on the password.html but i keep getting the error: 'msg.replace', any idea?