# Custom Checkout Validation - Two fields must have the same value : M2

Tags: magento2, validation, form-validation

I have read  [this](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145367/custom-checkout-validation-two-fields-must-have-the-same-value) URL for equalTo validation.

I have add custom field using LayoutProcessor.php file and set validation like this :

`'validation' => ['validate-no-empty' => false,'validate-password' => true,'min_text_len‌​gth' => 7, 'max_text_length' => 20,],`

all above validation is working good except **"equalTo"**.

I have try like this: , `"equalTo" => "#fieldname"` but still not working, can anyone help me, how can i use **"equalTo"** validation in **LayoutProcessor.php** file?

My Code:

```
<?php
namespace Packeg\Modulename\Plugin\Checkout\Model\Checkout;


class LayoutProcessor
{

    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    ) {


        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {




        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['before-shipping-method-form']['children']['password_1'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/password',
                'id' => 'password_1'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.password_1',
            'label' => 'Create Password',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => ['validate-no-empty' => false,'validate-password' => true,'min_text_len‌​gth' => 7, 'max_text_length' => 20,],
            'sortOrder' => 250,
            'id' => 'password_1'
        ];

        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
        ['shippingAddress']['children']['before-shipping-method-form']['children']['password_2'] = [
            'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
            'config' => [
                'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/password',
                'id' => 'password_2'
            ],
            'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.password_2',
            'label' => 'Re-enter Password',
            'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
            'visible' => true,
            'validation' => ['validate-no-empty' => true, 'validate-password2'=> true , "min_text_len‌​gth" => 7, "max_text_length" => 20],
            'sortOrder' => 255,
            'id' => 'password_2'
        ];



    }
        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide your code which you used in `LayoutProcessor.php`.

Comment: i have add my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if(!$customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {


            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['before-shipping-method-form']['children']['password_1'] = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/password',
                    'id' => 'password_1',

                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.password_1',
                'label' => 'Create Password',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => ['validate-no-empty' => false, 'validate-password' => true, 'min_text_len‌​gth' => 7, 'max_text_length' => 20,],
                'sortOrder' => 250,
                'id' => 'password_1'
            ];

            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']['children']
            ['shippingAddress']['children']['before-shipping-method-form']['children']['password_2'] = [
                'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract',
                'config' => [
                    'customScope' => 'shippingAddress',
                    'template' => 'ui/form/field',
                    'elementTmpl' => 'ui/form/element/password',
                    'id' => 'password_2'
                ],
                'dataScope' => 'shippingAddress.password_2',
                'label' => 'Re-enter Password',
                'provider' => 'checkoutProvider',
                'visible' => true,
                'validation' => ['validate-no-empty' => true, 'validate-password2' => true, "min_text_len‌​gth" => 7, "max_text_length" => 20,'equalTo'=>'[name="password_1"]'],
                'sortOrder' => 255,
                'id' => 'password_2'
            ];
```

I have added this `'equalTo'=>'[name="password_1"]'` in